# Trying to read a .txt file and pull out a specific line based off of a letter entered by user

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have this file with information from the periodic table in a .txt file and Im trying to write a program that allows the user to input the element symbol then read through the file until it finds that symbol and spits out information about that element. At first I got the program to output the cout statement with no information, and now its completely skipping this section after the symbol is entered and going right to the next. Here is my code.

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream myfile;
string line;

myfile.open("txt file");

fin.open("txt file", ios::app);


while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
    fin >> element >> symbol >> atomic_number >> atomic_mass >> physical_state >> density >> melting_point >> boiling_point >> created >> chemical_group >> electronegativity;

    if (line == symbol)
    {
        cout << "information from above"
        break;
    }

    fin.close();
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: What do the contents of your data file look like?

Comment: Also, mixing `std::getline()` and formatted input using `>>` is almost always a bad idea. Tends to result in the former giving empty strings because of newlines left on the stream by the latter.

Comment: Not validating that formatted input succeeded before trying to use those variables is also a bad idea.

Comment: Its basically this (Hydrogen H 1 1.0079 Gas   0.00008988 14.01 K 20.28 K No Hydrogen    2.2)  but for every element on the periodic table.

Answer (score 0):

**Trying to read a .txt file and pull out a specific line based off of a letter entered by user.**

Here is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"string"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream fi("1.txt", ofstream::in);
    ofstream fo("2.txt", ofstream::out);
    string buf;
    string s1;
    cin >> s1;
    while (fi >> buf)
    {
        if (buf.find(s1) != string::npos) break;

    }
    fo << buf << endl;

        fi.close();
        fo.close();

    return 0;
}
```

1.txt is the file you are trying to read. Save the pull out specific line to 2.txt. "s1" is the string entered by the user.

Hope this code is helpful to you.